# Modal form sheet view controller on iPad - fade to black

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, background, modal-dialog

When presenting a modal form sheet view controller on the iPad the remainder of the screen not taken up by the form sheet dims (but remains transparent). Is there any way to get it to dim all the way to black (i.e. become opaque)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the dim is always with alpha, to do what you need you will have to implement your own modal transition sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an image:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];    
    backgroundImage = [backgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:40];
    CGSize theSize = actionSheet.frame.size;
    // draw the background image and replace layer content  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
    theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [[actionSheet layer] setContents:(id)backgroundImage.CGImage];
}
```

Or do it this way:

```
CGSize mySize = myActionSheet.bounds.size;
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, mySize.x, mySize.y);
UIImageView *blackView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect] autorelease];
[redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.view insertSubview:blackView atIndex:0];
```

You can also change the actionSheetStyle

```
MyActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
MyActionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this with a modal view controller on the iPad in form sheet style?

Answer (score 0):

Considering there does not seem to be a pretty solution, an easy hack can be done by inserting a subview with a black background on top of your presentingViewController in prepareForSegue(). Then just before you dismiss the formsheet, get the presentingViewController (self.presentingViewController) and remove the added view.